# Javascript-firefox: Table Rows are impossible to highlight

Tags: javascript, mozilla

```
document.onmouseover= function(event) {
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event;                     
    var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement; 
    if(target.tagName == 'TR') {            
            target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }else{
            target.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
};
document.onmouseout= function(event) {
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event;                     
    var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement; 
    target.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
};
```

TR elements never highlight nor does onmouseover event fire for this. TD elements work fine. What explains this behavior and how can I make onmouseover fire when it touches TR element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing your code to:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('TR');
for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
  rows[i].onmouseover = function (event) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }

  rows[i].onmouseout = function (event) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Asv4v/3/

Comment: That would work, but not as efficient as one handler and much more likely to cause memory leak (as you would have to de-regester all listeners instead of just one).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that this would have something to do with the bubbling/capturing model.  Declaring the handler on the document itself leaves a lot of elements in between that could be capturing the event before it reaches document.  Anyway, I do something similar to this, but put my handler on the `<table>` element.  It is also worth noting that most major javascript libraries have frameworks to help with this.  I personally like YUI or Prototype, though many other prefer Dojo or JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
document.onmouseover = function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td'){
        e.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        e.target.onmouseout = function(){
            this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }
    } 
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CV86g/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your tr exactly contains it's tds, and hence the TDs overlap the TRs in the DOM; i.e., the "target" will never be the TR. To test this, make 2 TRs, the first with 2 TDs and the second with 1 (or see the linked jsfiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/Asv4v/6/

Edit: Interestingly enough, in FFox if there is a missing TD the target is a "TR", but in chrome the target is a "Table"

Short answer: To get the behaviour I think you're looking for replace the "TR" in the js to "TD"

Comment: that would just select td now. i need to get the actual TR element